# TI83+. Math-> Solver. Why does it give different solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, diophantine-equations, calculator

Not sure if anyone still uses this one....
Recall the keystrokes:
Math 0:Solver
Up arrow
Enter equation
Press ENTER

You will now be at a prompt displaying the equation,
and a line saying x=*###*   (prior solution)
and a line below saying bound=

Then you type Alpha->ENTER (solve)
I am getting different answers based on what is already entered in the x=**__** line

Did anyone else look into why this is?
What is the calculator doing?
Is there an accepted way to get the "right" root?
Do you clear the x=*_*_ first?

Comment: What are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'd imagine you're putting in a bound that contains multiple roots, but just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall correctly, it finds the solution nearest to what is already in the `x=` line. I think the calculator is using some sort of numerical method, and what you enter in `x=` is the initial guess for the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I have a TI-84 Plus, which works basically in the same way. It doesn't simply apply a formula to resolve the equation, but actually builds up closer approximations from a guess. This is also why it can't give precise values such as $\sqrt 2$, the way simpler non-graphical calculators can.

Comment: I remember a site with a rough description on how these calculators solve stuff like equations, but I can't seem to find it. I'll try to find and add that reference ASAP. Other problem is that one needs an account to access TI site info.